# Can I create two contextual action bars?

Tags: android, split, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar

I'm designing an editor that will have context-specific actions on two related items, for example, insert image, clear, etc.  It makes sense to show both items simultaneously on a larger display.  I'd rather not require the user to switch back and forth between tabs.

[image: Layout Sketch - any distortion in the image is certainly due to warping in your cheap-as-free monitor]

Is it possible and/or recommended to have two different [contextual action bars](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#contextual) to support a configuration like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one at a time. The contextual action bar (a.k.a., action mode) replaces the regular action bar. Since you only have one action bar, you can only have one contextual action bar at a time. Since the user is (hopefully) only working on one "context" at a time, this (hopefully) will not be a big limitation, so long as it is visually obvious what she is performing the contextual actions upon.

Comment: After re-reading the [design guide](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#contextual), they do state that this is intended to be used after selecting items.  Maybe the right way to approach would be to require the user to first "select" the photo, and then display the action bar.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod: Absolutely. A long-tap, for example, might put a highlight around the photo in question, then trigger the contextual action bar. There are few standards around the trigger mechanism (single tap, long-tap, check a checkbox adjacent to the item, etc.), so you have lots of flexibility there. As a bonus, you could elect to support them choosing *both* photos and performing a contextual operation on the pair simultaneously.